# Laravel Controller -> API class

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm struggling with how to do this correctly following best practices. It might be difficult to explain but i'll try my best here.

I have an external API I need to make very many different calls to. So what I did was creating a class in the App folder called Api.php for now. It's using Guzzle for API calls.

In the Controller for the view I create the Api object in the needed functions and call the corresponding function in the API class.

**Controller**

```
public function uploadDevice(Request $request)
{
  ## Validation etc is performed

  // Calling the API
  $api = new Api();
  $api->uploadDevice();
}
```

**Api.php**

```
class Api
{

    private $token;

    public function __construct(){}

    public function checkIfHasToken(){}

    public function getTokenFromSession(){}

    public function getFreshToken(){}

    public function uploadDevice(){}

}
```

**Some questions**

1. The *checkIfHasToken()* needs to be called before every request. Should it be done in the `constructor`, `first in each function doing API calls` or `directly from the Controller`?
2. Exceptions : Where should I do the Try/catch etc ? Should it be done in the Api class where it's needed or in the Controller by calling each and every function from the API class and wrapping it in try/catch?
3. Redirects : I want to redirect back to the Route the request came from with every possible errors or success message included. So if I have a try/catch I want to redirect with the result of the catch included. Where to put this logic? Redirecting from the nested function does not seem to work. So then I'm back to calling each and every function in the Api class from the Controller one by one and handle the exceptions/errors/validations separately in the Controller?

Maybe I'm thinking too much about this or making it more complicated than it needs to be. Not sure anymore.

Comment: Are the API's that you are calling, like uploadDevice() going to external services?

Comment: I use [Adapter Pattern (wrapper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#PHP) for any kind of API integrations, have you checked out that the API you are trying to consume has no package already out there in the wild? Also I use container for resolving it so no `new Api;` but type-hinting it in the constructor instead. If its not simple class you need to bind it in a service provider.

Comment: @DevinGray Yes. uploadDevice does a API request with Guzzle with the token in the header.

Comment: Then I believe you are looking to create a service/helper class as best practice. Give me a few minutes to build an answer or open a chat with me and I'll show you some ideas

Comment: @DevinGray That'd be great. Thanks. Waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Kyslik The API has no suche thing for sure. It's a good API, but not widely used at all. Very limited to a niche market.

Comment: Is it top-secret API? Just share it here; it may help others to help you.

Comment: @Kyslik No not at all. API is for Cisco APIC-EM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Controller
public function __construct(ApiService $apiService)
{
    $this->api = $apiService;
}


public function uploadDevice(Request $request)
{
    // Ensure that the user has a token in a custom HTTP request or in a middleware somewhere
    try {
        $this->api->uploadDevice();
    }
    catch (Exception $exception){
        return redirect()->back();
        //You can include errors from $exception here.
    }
}

// Service
class ApiService
{

    public function uploadDevice()
    {
        return 'I did a thing';
    }

}
```

Explaination

Laravel has many ways to do the same thing, it is all about what you need and how you want your application to scale.

Checking if a token is present or valid should be done in a middleware.

A try catch can be anywhere depending on how much you need to see in the exception, normally just in a controller is ok, but you can
    do this in many ways. I personally like to make an event listener
    for any http error.

Return redirect back from the controller will be fine to always redirect to the place that invoked the controller

Comment: Thanks. Coming back to it after lunch.

Comment: Would the middlware just check if the token is present in session (true/false) or would it fetch it aswell?

Comment: Usually I would build a JWT helper for API tokens, to run a number of functions, check if exists, check if valid, if not check for refresh, retreive new etc. Middleware is a class so you can do a lot in them, but they shouldn't be too heavy. Most JWT packages have this already built in

Answer (score 0):

> The checkIfHasToken() needs to be called before every request. Should
>   it be done in the constructor, first in each function doing API calls
>   or directly from the Controller?

If it needs to be called for every request, I suggest making it middleware as it's made for this purpose.

> Exceptions : Where should I do the Try/catch etc ? Should it be done
>   in the Api class where it's needed or in the Controller by calling
>   each and every function from the API class and wrapping it in
>   try/catch?

This depends, if you want to be able to control the output when an exception occurs then you probably want it in your controller. If you can program something to do when the exception occurs (return unsuccessful for instance), do it in a lower level (api).

> Redirects : I want to redirect back to the Route the request came from
>   with every possible errors or success message included. So if I have a
>   try/catch I want to redirect with the result of the catch included.
>   Where to put this logic? Redirecting from the nested function does not
>   seem to work. So then I'm back to calling each and every function in
>   the Api class from the Controller one by one and handle the
>   exceptions/errors/validations separately in the Controller?

You can go back by returning `redirect()->back()` as the response, the best way to show errors would to include them somewhere. I suggest using `session()->flash()` for this. These calls can be made from the try/catch.